# Загрузить изображение в base64 post-запросом на сайт с помощью nodejs и php

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

Как загрузить на сайт изображение в base64, отправив post-запрос с nodejs с именем изображения и самим base64?

Пользователь хочет загрузить картинку на сайт. Он её загружает, вводит имя для изображения и нажимает "загрузить", отправляя запрос на сервер уже с изображением base64. Сервер проверяет самого пользователя и отправляет post-запрос на, к примеру, upload.php. (дальше не знаю как реализовать) В upload.php проверяется само изображение на то, что это изображение, загружает его в папку 'img' и сервер получает успех.

Запрос отправить я могу, а вот в php я тыква. Прошу вас помочь, буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 0):

Так как было понятно, что мне никто не поможет, пришлось помочь самому себе и клеить решение. В итоге, спустя огромные паутины гугла, я вылепил такое решение моего вопроса.
Кому помог, буду рад, если Вы отметите мой ответ полезным :)

nodejs:

```
const request = require('request');

async function doRequest(icon, way) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request.post({uri: "http://site.com/upload.php", form: {img: icon, way: way}}, (error, res, body) => {
            if (!error && res.statusCode == 200) {
                resolve(body);
            } else {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    });
}

const load_img = await doRequest(base64, 'img/name');
let icon = null;

if (load_img.split(' ')[0] == 'success') {
    icon = load_img.split(' ')[1];
    console.log(`загружено! путь - "${icon}"`);
} else {
    console.log(load_img);
}
```

php:

```
<?php

$icon = $_POST['img'];
$way = $_POST['way'];

if (preg_match('/^data:image\/(\w+);base64,/', $icon, $type)) {
    $icon = substr($icon, strpos($icon, ',') + 1);
    $type = strtolower($type[1]);

    if (!in_array($type, [ 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png' ])) {
        die('invalid image type');
    }

    $icon = base64_decode($icon);

    if ($icon === false) {
        die('base64_decode failed');
    }
} else {
    die('did not match data URI with image data');
}

$way = "{$way}.{$type}";

file_put_contents($way, $icon);
echo "success {$way}";

?>
```

Спасибо Stack Overflow, что ты существуешь!